# Why actually at resonance the inductive and capacitive reactance cancel each other?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, oscillators, inductance, resonance

I am learning about series LC circuit that is in resonance. It says it is when the impedance offered is minimum due to the angular frequency being at a particular value(1/√LC).People say that they are out of phase and hence cancel each other which I don't understand. What actually happens at resonant frequency that causes the voltage to drop at only the resistor? Hopefully,you could provide me with an intuition.

Comment: If this is a series circuit and the signal is at resonant frequency, then the net impedance will go down and the current through R should surge; why then should there be a voltage drop?

Answer (score 2):

The current through the inductor, L, at any instant is the same as that in the wires of the capacitor, C, as the L and the C are parts of a series circuit. If that current is $I=I_0 \cos \omega t$, then the pds across the L and the C are
$$V_L=\omega L\ I_0\cos\left(\omega t -\tfrac \pi 2\right)\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ V_C=\frac 1 {\omega C}\ I_0\cos\left(\omega t +\tfrac \pi 2\right)$$
Using $\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B\ –\sin A \sin B $,  we can write these as
$$V_L=\omega L\ I_0\sin\omega t  \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ V_C=-\frac 1 {\omega C}\ I_0\sin\omega t$$
As the components are in series these pds add algebraically, and will clearly cancel to zero if $\omega L=\frac 1 {\omega C}$.